# Understanding javascript call function

Tags: javascript

```
'use strict';

let worker = {
  someMethod() {
    return 4;
  },

  slow(x) {
    return x * this.somemethod();
  }
};

function wrapper(func) {
  return function(x) {
    let result = this.func(x);  // **
    return result;
  };
}

worker.slow = wrapper(worker.slow);
alert( worker.slow(2) );
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
  TypeError:  this.func is not a function
```

If I replace the problematic line at ** with this:

```
let result = func.call(this, x);
```

I get the expected output.  In this case it's 8.

I'm wondering why the way it's written is the wrong way to get "this" ie the object worker.  In other words, how does the call function get the right object i.e. worker ?

Comment: I wrote this about what `this` is and isn't, maybe it will help clarify https://gist.github.com/ddlsmurf/4c4c56e86b6f9a647c7aeec86f90b2cc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's failing is that in the problematic line (highlighted with // **), you're effectively calling worker.func(x), which does not exist; You're not referring to the passed in variable at all.

If you add a function (func) to your worker, e.g.

```
let worker = {
  someMethod: function() {
    return 4;
  },

  slow: function(x) {
    return x * this.somemethod();
  },
  func: function (x) {
     return x * 10;
  }
};
```

And call as above e.g.

```
worker.slow = wrapper(worker.slow);
console.log( worker.slow(2) );
```

You'd find it works, though this is not what you really want!

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, any function call `obj.f(ArgumentList)` will be desugared into `f.call(obj, ArgumentList...)`(see [ecma-262 7.3.12](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-call))

When `wrapper(worker.slow)` got a call, the function `slow` is passed into the wrapper and it produces another function which **captured** `func` argument. However, that function returned by wrapper is not called yet.

At a moment of the function call `alert( worker.slow(2) )`
`func` mean the argument that got captured in the `closure` and `func.call(this, x)` means it will call that function with the current caller, which is `worker`.

```
Therefore, `func.call(this,x)` will be `func.call(worker, x) `
which works because `func` exists in the closure.
```

while `this` means the reference to a current caller to the `function(x){ ... }`

```
Hence, `this.func(x)` will be `worker.func(x)` 
which `func` does not exist in `worker`.
```

if you try to insert `console.log(func)` and `console.log(this)`
in that function, you will see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the desugaring concept.  I was not aware of it before.  The line marked with ** will desugar to this.func.call(this, x).  This is invalid per Terry's point above.  Hence we need to call the primitive ourself.

Comment: By the way, if anyone else is unfamiliar with desugaring read this blog:  http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/.  It helped me a lot.